# How to find data from a previous month in sql starting from day 1 in the SELECT in sql?

Tags: mysql, t-sql, plsql

```
SELECT 

    team, team_name, COUNT(*) AS c 
FROM 

    [helpdesk].[dbo].[inpc] , helpdesk.dbo.teams
```

WHERE
        team = teams.id 
        AND st IN (4, 5) 
        AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dd_1, 102) > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY 
        team, team_name

Comment: Your tags should contain the language this comes from, in your case MySQL, TSQL, PLSQL? Also, please do not post a 'question' containing only the code. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *please stop commenting if not constructive comments, related to question, flag comments that are not, see [be-nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)*

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: i know but the enviornment iam working in is a bit old we even still work with asp classic

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really a painful SQL Server date olympics question.  We can phrase the requirement of the previous month as a date on or after the first of the previous month and strictly before the first of the current month.

```
SELECT
    team,
    team_name,
    COUNT(*) as c
FROM [helpdesk].[dbo].[inpc], helpdesk.dbo.teams
WHERE
    team = teams.id AND
    st IN (4,5) AND
    dd_1 >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())), 0) AND
    dd_1 <  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())), 0)
GROUP BY
    team,
    team_name;
```

Also, as others have pointed out, you should use explicit join syntax.  I'm not sure your current join even makes sense, as it appears to be a cross join.

Comment: it says the DATEADD function requires 3 arguments !!

Comment: @ahmedbayan Why are you shouting at me?  I had a small typo in my answer, you can try it again.

Comment: i didnt shout i just wrote what have appeared to me it was uppercase :D :D